# Python - All list combinations using addition

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance

I have a list that is in this form:
`["Name/num1/num2/num3/num4/num5", ...]`

For example:
`available = ["a/1/2/3/4/5", "b/5/4/3/2/4", "c/4/3/2/1/3"]`

I am trying to create every possible combination of items in `available`, where the sum of num5 of each item in the combination (e.g. `for a is 5`, `for b is 1`, `for c is 5`) is less than `MAXNUM` (e.g. 3000).

To clarify with an example, the program will create a generator for `available` above and `MAXNUM = 9` which can be turned into the following list:

`[["a/1/2/3/4/5", "b/5/4/3/2/4"], ["a/1/2/3/4/5", c/4/3/2/1/3], [b/5/4/3/2/4, b/5/4/3/2/4], [b/5/4/3/2/4, "c/4/3/2/1/3"], ["c/4/3/2/1/3", "c/4/3/2/1/3", "c/4/3/2/1/3"]]`

Note: This code needs to return a result with `available` having 100 items, and `MAXNUM = 3000` within a reasonable time (No more than 10 minutes ideally)

Edit: Here is my code in a practical use, as requested:

```
import itertools
import sys
import time

sys.setrecursionlimit(10000000)

#["Name/Carbs/Protein/Fat/Vitamins/Calories"]
available = ['Fiddleheads/3/1/0/3/80', 'Fireweed Shoots/3/0/0/4/150', 'Prickly Pear Fruit/2/1/1/3/190', 'Huckleberries/2/0/0/6/80', 'Rice/7/1/0/0/90', 'Camas Bulb/1/2/5/0/120', 'Beans/1/4/3/0/120', 'Wheat/6/2/0/0/130', 'Crimini Mushrooms/3/3/1/1/200', 'Corn/5/2/0/1/230', 'Beet/3/1/1/3/230', 'Tomato/4/1/0/3/240', 'Raw Fish/0/3/7/0/200', 'Raw Meat/0/7/3/0/250', 'Tallow/0/0/8/0/200', 'Scrap Meat/0/5/5/0/50', 'Prepared Meat/0/4/6/0/600', 'Raw Roast/0/6/5/0/800', 'Raw Sausage/0/4/8/0/500', 'Raw Bacon/0/3/9/0/600', 'Prime Cut/0/9/4/0/600', 'Cereal Germ/5/0/7/3/20', 'Bean Paste/3/5/7/0/40', 'Flour/15/0/0/0/50', 'Sugar/15/0/0/0/50', 'Camas Paste/3/2/10/0/60', 'Cornmeal/9/3/3/0/60', 'Huckleberry Extract/0/0/0/15/60', 'Yeast/0/8/0/7/60', 'Oil/0/0/15/0/120', 'Infused Oil/0/0/12/3/120', 'Simple Syrup/12/0/3/0/400', 'Rice Sludge/10/1/0/2/450', 'Charred Beet/3/0/3/7/470', 'Camas Mash/1/2/9/1/500', 'Campfire Beans/1/9/3/0/500', 'Wilted Fiddleheads/4/1/0/8/500', 'Boiled Shoots/3/0/1/9/510', 'Charred Camas Bulb/2/3/7/1/510', 'Charred Tomato/8/1/0/4/510', 'Charred Corn/8/1/0/4/530', 'Charred Fish/0/9/4/0/550', 'Charred Meat/0/10/10/0/550', 'Wheat Porridge/10/4/0/10/510', 'Charred Sausage/0/11/15/0/500', 'Fried Tomatoes/12/3/9/2/560', 'Bannock/15/3/8/0/600', 'Fiddlehead Salad/6/6/0/14/970', 'Campfire Roast/0/16/12/0/1000', 'Campfire Stew/5/12/9/4/1200', 'Wild Stew/8/5/5/12/1200', 'Fruit Salad/8/2/2/10/900', 'Meat Stock/5/8/9/3/700', 'Vegetable Stock/11/1/2/11/700', 'Camas Bulb Bake/12/7/5/4/400', 'Flatbread/17/8/3/0/500', 'Huckleberry Muffin/10/5/4/11/450', 'Baked Meat/0/13/17/0/600', 'Baked Roast/4/13/8/7/900', 'Huckleberry Pie/9/5/4/16/1300', 'Meat Pie/7/11/11/5/1300', 'Basic Salad/13/6/6/13/800', 'Simmered Meat/6/18/13/5/900', 'Vegetable Medley/9/5/8/20/900', 'Vegetable Soup/12/4/7/19/1200', 'Crispy Bacon/0/18/26/0/600', 'Stuffed Turkey/9/16/12/7/1500']

global AllSP, AllNames
AllSP = []
AllNames = []

def findcombs(totalNames, totalCarbs, totalProtein, totalFat, totalVitamins, totalNutrients, totalCalories, MAXCALORIES):
    doneit = False
    for each in available:
        each = each.split("/")
        name = each[0]
        carbs = float(each[1])
        protein = float(each[2])
        fat = float(each[3])
        vitamins = float(each[4])
        nutrients = carbs+protein+fat+vitamins
        calories = float(each[5])
#        print(totalNames, totalCalories, calories, each)
        if sum(totalCalories)+calories <= MAXCALORIES:
            doneit = True
            totalNames2 = totalNames[::]
            totalCarbs2 = totalCarbs[::]
            totalProtein2 = totalProtein[::]
            totalFat2 = totalFat[::]
            totalVitamins2 = totalVitamins[::]
            totalCalories2 = totalCalories[::]
            totalNutrients2 = totalNutrients[::]

            totalNames2.append(name)
            totalCarbs2.append(carbs)
            totalProtein2.append(protein)
            totalFat2.append(fat)
            totalVitamins2.append(vitamins)
            totalCalories2.append(calories)
            totalNutrients2.append(nutrients)
#            print("    ", totalNames2, totalCarbs2, totalProtein2, totalFat2, totalVitamins2, totalNutrients2, totalCalories2)
            findcombs(totalNames2, totalCarbs2, totalProtein2, totalFat2, totalVitamins2, totalNutrients2, totalCalories2, MAXCALORIES)
        else:
            #find SP
            try:
                carbs    = sum([x * y for x, y in zip(totalCalories, totalCarbs)])    / sum(totalCalories)
                protein  = sum([x * y for x, y in zip(totalCalories, totalProtein)])  / sum(totalCalories)
                fat      = sum([x * y for x, y in zip(totalCalories, totalFat)])      / sum(totalCalories)
                vitamins = sum([x * y for x, y in zip(totalCalories, totalVitamins)]) / sum(totalCalories)
                balance  = (carbs+protein+fat+vitamins)/(2*max([carbs,protein,fat,vitamins]))
                thisSP   = sum([x * y for x, y in zip(totalCalories, totalNutrients)]) / sum(totalCalories) * balance + 12
            except:
                thisSP = 0
            #add SP and names to two lists
            AllSP.append(thisSP)
            AllNames.append(totalNames)

def main(MAXCALORIES):
    findcombs([], [], [], [], [], [], [], MAXCALORIES)
    index = AllSP.index(max(AllSP))
    print()
    print(AllSP[index], "  ", AllNames[index])

for i in range(100, 3000, 10):
    start = time.time()
    main(i)
    print("Calories:", i, ">>> Time:", time.time()-start)
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what specific problem did you encounter?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille The time the code takes to run. With 100 items and MAXNUM=3000 my code was predicted to take well over 100 years

Comment: Then you should show us your code, and add this comment in your question.

Comment: knapsack problem?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I have added my code, in the use that I am trying to make it work for.

Comment: @Ajax1234 The string is in the format `"Name/num1/num2/num3/num4/num5"`. It is `num5` which I am finding the sum of in each combination.

Comment: The number of possible combinations, according to your data, is really huge  - much more than you could possibly make use of. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are the value ranges always between 1 and 5, inclusive?

Comment: @Ajax1234 The value ranges are from 20 to 2000

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I am trying to find the "optimal diet" for a game known as Eco, given a list of foods

Comment: You will have to find a different approach, you would very certainly starve before you're halfway trying all possible combinations...

Comment: @ThierryLathuille What other approach would you recommend?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to set a maximum (lower than 150) on the number of food items in a combination ?   If you have one food item with the minimum values  F/20/20/20/20/20 and a maximum of 3000, you could use this item 150 times before reaching the maximum on any of its components.  Also, is it possible for a component to have a value of 0 or is 20 the absolute minimum ?

Comment: @AlainT. For my use a maximum of 151 would be appropriate. The absolute minimum is 20, since I have removed any foods which give 0 or less (negative calories).

Comment: I was thinking of a much lower value than that (like 5 or so).  Otherwise the number of combinations is astronomical.  For example 10 food categories out of the 100 would create 17310309456440 combinations.  Unless you have a majority of the categories that have component values > 1000 (or some other mutual exclusion rules), it will be very hard to optimize the process.

Comment: Are you suggesting that a combination should be no longer than 5, or that there should be no more than 5 different foods in a combination? I can limit the amount of food in a combination to 6, if that would help. @AlainT.

Comment: A combination with no more than 5 food items is what I was suggesting but there could be other means to cut down on the astronomical numbers if there are some exclusion rules that can be applied.  to quickly determine that 2,3,4 or 5 food items cannot be combined for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the high number of possibilities, perhaps you should approach the use of this information differently.  For example, if the usage context is selection of foods given a prior selection, you could simply provide the information on how many of each food type can be had without going over the maximum

```
foofInfo = [ food.split("/") for food in available ]
foofInfo = { food[0]:tuple([int(v) for v in food[1:]]) for food in available } #name:(carbs,proteins,fat,vitamins,nutrients,calories)

calFood = {}
for name,(_,_,_,_,calories) in foofInfo.items():
    if calories not in calFood: calFood[calories] = []
    calFood[calories].append(name)

maxCalories = 3000
for calories,foods in calFood.items():
    maxCount = maxCalories//calories
    print("Up to ",maxCount," of ",", ".join(foods))
```

So you could propose a progressive refinement of the available options rather than a bazillion combinations:

```
Up to  37  of  Fiddleheads, Huckleberries
Up to  20  of  Fireweed Shoots
Up to  15  of  Prickly Pear Fruit
Up to  33  of  Rice
Up to  25  of  Camas Bulb, Beans, Oil, Infused Oil
Up to  23  of  Wheat
Up to  15  of  Crimini Mushrooms, Raw Fish, Tallow
Up to  13  of  Corn, Beet
Up to  12  of  Tomato
Up to  12  of  Raw Meat
Up to  60  of  Scrap Meat, Flour, Sugar
Up to  5  of  Prepared Meat, Raw Bacon, Prime Cut, Bannock, Baked Meat, Crispy Bacon
Up to  3  of  Raw Roast, Basic Salad
Up to  6  of  Raw Sausage, Camas Mash, Campfire Beans, Wilted Fiddleheads, Charred Sausage, Flatbread
Up to  150  of  Cereal Germ
Up to  75  of  Bean Paste
Up to  50  of  Camas Paste, Cornmeal, Huckleberry Extract, Yeast
Up to  7  of  Simple Syrup, Camas Bulb Bake
Up to  6  of  Rice Sludge, Huckleberry Muffin
Up to  6  of  Charred Beet
Up to  5  of  Boiled Shoots, Charred Camas Bulb, Charred Tomato, Wheat Porridge
Up to  5  of  Charred Corn
Up to  5  of  Charred Fish, Charred Meat
Up to  5  of  Fried Tomatoes
Up to  3  of  Fiddlehead Salad
Up to  3  of  Campfire Roast
Up to  2  of  Campfire Stew, Wild Stew, Vegetable Soup
Up to  3  of  Fruit Salad, Baked Roast, Simmered Meat, Vegetable Medley
Up to  4  of  Meat Stock, Vegetable Stock
Up to  2  of  Huckleberry Pie, Meat Pie
Up to  2  of  Stuffed Turkey
```

Answer (score 1):

Right, so the task for `N` foods has time and space complexity of `O(exp(N))`. What you need is some heuristic search like [A* (link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) which follows some idea of 'how good' one incomplete combination is to direct its further search. As a result you will find not the best solution, but a practical good solution within limited time. Alternatives are genetic algorithms, simulated annealing, and other optimization algorithm. Note that you must define a metric of how good each combination is!

I was using the package `astar` (https://github.com/jrialland/python-astar) in my video game AI, and it exceeded my expectations.

Further suggestions: use `namedtuple` to make your code more readable, otherwise you will hate finding bugs and extending it:

```
from collections import namedtuple

food = namedtuple('Food', 'name carbs protein fat vitamins calories')

bananas = food('bananas', 10, 15, 20, 10, 100)
oranges = food('oranges', carbs=10, protein=15, fat=20, vitamins=10, calories=100)
print(bananas.calories, oranges.fat)
```

Comment: Great idea! How would I implement this to my practical use, since a single food item could change the balance multiplier from 0.5 to 2 at the end, which means the best solutions could be missed

Comment: There is no magical fix, since the problem is complex in its nature (its NP, or non-polynomial). A simple solution is to run many times, shuffling the food each time - this way you are less likely to be left with only bad solutions.

Comment: Final question, what could I use (e.g. not very balanced) to cut out bad results?

Comment: Its you who defines the score for intermediate solution, so just put a lot of negative points using the if statements and any formulas that you feel are appropriate. Just try it out, you will get the hang of it.